# XSS on asp pages

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, xss

I have a website which have many forms that are saved to db and shown to users, and needs to allow html.

Currenty, no input is sanitized agains XSS attacks.
As there is big amount of forms that can inject some script or bad code, finding and sanizating all inputs would take some time.

Im using Entity Framework so first idea that i got is to call method before db.SaveChanges(), which would check changed entities text fields, and then sanitized them.

Is there any major flows in this method?

```
public static void SanitizeDbContext(DbEntities db)
{
  var changes = from e in db.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                where e.State != EntityState.Unchanged
                select e;

  foreach (var change in changes)
  {
     //Sanatize if field is string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd much rather do sanitization as soon as possible, so that you can log malicious responses and attach an IP, or even a username, to the response for further research.

Furthermore, by coupling the sanitization to SaveChanges, you make a few assertions which may prove to be incorrect later on.

1. You will always use EF. If you stop doing so, I hope to god that you don't forget to transfew the sanitation method to the new ORM, or you'll have no XSS protection any more.
2. You have no single place in your application where a response is sent back directly based on user input, rather than going via the database. If there are any such places, the response will be based on the unsanitized result, which could cause issues (IE: a Non-Persistent XSS attack).

Comment: Well, i agree, sanitizing at SaveChanges is maybe 2 late in some cases.

Comment: So, the best way is to just sanitize input as it is posted on website i guess. I thought about handler on every postback/post/get to check all keys... dunno if this is legit solution ( or good)

Comment: What I did at some point is made custom extensions of TextBoxes etc which automagically santize input data, and use those whenever the stuff people had to input was potentially dangerous.